# Change the value of external Javascript with PHP in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How can I change the value of a js variable in a PHP foreach loop?

The js needs to be external.

This is a piece of the `index.php` here I want to get the output $prozent in the javascript, I don't know how to get a PHP variable to execute a js every time in a loop, the js is a chart. I get the chart in the loop in the `echo'<div class="chart-wrapper">` with a [this](http://codepen.io/Siddharth11/pen/LVQmjN) chart js.

```
<?php
                $sql = //SQL query
                $res = mysql_query($sql);
                $i = 0;
                $survey = array();
                 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                    $survey[$i]['label'] = $row['Label'];
                    $i++;
                }

                    foreach ($survey as $survey) {    
                    echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
                    echo '<div class="front face">';                

            echo "<h3> ".$survey['label']."<br>";
            $sql = //SQL Query
            $res = mysql_query($sql) ;
            $sql = //SQL Query
                $resSum = mysql_query($sql) ;
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resSum)) {
                $survey['ausgabe'] = $row['sum(a.answer)'];
                 }


                $anzahlreihen = mysql_num_rows($res);
                if ($anzahlreihen > 0) {    
                $prozent = $anzahlreihen * $survey['ausgabe'];
                   //bunch of ifelse statements
              //This is the variable i want to get in the js    
            echo (round( $prozent, 2));
                    echo '</font>';
                }
                }
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div class="back face center">';
            echo'<div class="chart-wrapper">
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways PHP and Javascript can interact.

Use AJAX to request a PHP script which returns JSON or have PHP output the following example HTML;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var variable = value;
</script>
```

Comment: You could also imagine a php handler returning a full js file as output. And in your AJAX alternativ, it's worth notinh you don't necessarily return a JSON formatted answer from your php, it could be anything, although JSON(P) is generally the best fit...

Comment: Indeed, rethink the structure of your logic.

Comment: @doveyg Could it be possible if i take the variables multiple times out of the innerhtml with js?

Comment: That would work, yes. Do you need to display it though?

Comment: It would be nice, im seaching, but my js dont start with a function, and i dont know whitch function i need to call for execute the whole thing :(

Comment: You should write a new function, one that does what you need it to minimally do, then just call that function outside any other functions. You don't even need to write a function.